# Cannot insert date(Y-m-d H:i:s) in Postgres "timestamp"

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, timestamp

I am trying to insert data in Postgres with cakephp which includes a date.

The column in my database is a `timestamp without timezone` and I have a datetime string `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` (also tried with an int).

Must I cast that value?

Comment: Show us your statement and your error message, please.

Comment: Can you give an example for a concrete value and perhaps the used INSERT statement as well?

Answer (score 1):

You **do not** have to cast the inserted values as long as the text literal is unambiguous and in accepted format.

Don't mistake a *date* ('2011-10-21') for a *timestamp* ('2011-10-21 12:10:23').
This is perfectly legal for a **timestamp**:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (timestamp_col)
VALUES ('2011-01-01 0:0:0');
```

But a **date** you have to cast, resulting in '2011-01-01 0:0:0' in this case:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (timestamp_col)
VALUES ('2011-01-01'::timestamp);
```

ISO 8601 format 'yyyy-mm-dd' for a date and 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' for a timestmap are [unambiguous for any locale](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html). Other formats may depend on your locale.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
'Y-m-d H:i:s'::timestamp
```

Don't forget single quotes

for example

```
select '2011-01-01'::timestamp
```

Comment: I spent hours with google and just a second after posting my question here I found the reason, why my statement raises an error...

Comment: The field expected an array. Now I changed it and it seems to work.